# What is the function of the equation set in the definition of a polyhedron？

Tags: convex-analysis, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry

In the Chapter 2 of *Convex Optimization* by Boyd and Vandenberghe.
The definition of a polyhedron is as follows:

> A *polyhedron* is defined as the solution set of a finite number of linear equalities and inequalities :
>   $$\mathcal P = \{x : a_j^Tx\leqslant b_j, j=1,\ldots,m, c_j^Tx=d_j, j=1,\ldots,p\}. $$

But in the example shown in Fig. 2.11, shown as follows: [image]

I could not find where the hyper planes (i.e., equations) are, and thus I could not understand the function of equations here. Why equations are needed to define a polyhedron?

Comment: Each hyperplane is a linear equation (or inequality) in the variables.  Example in three dimensions:  $z < x + 2 y$.

Comment: The hyperplanes are the sets $\{x : a_j^Tx = b_j\}$.  If you turn the equalities into inequalities, you get the sets $\{x : a_j^Tx \leq b_j\}$, half-spaces; and if you intersect all the half-spaces you get the polyhedron.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That is not a hyperplane. A hyperplane is an affine subspace of dimension one less than the ambient space.

Comment: @JairTaylor:  the plane defined by $z = x + 2$ is of dimension $2$... indeed one less than the three-dimensional $x,y,z$ space.  The *in*equality is useful for stating which side of the (two-dimensional) hyperplane the solution must lie.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sure.  $z=x+2$ is a hyperplane, but $z < x + 2y$ is not.

Comment: Just like I said.

Comment: Choose a vector $a\in\Bbb R^n$, choose a number $b\in\Bbb R$. Try to plot the set of all $x\in\Bbb R^n$ with $a^\top x = b$ or $a^\top x \le b$, or at least try to reason about how this set must look like. What happens when you now have several of these (in)equalities?

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

The Figure 2.11 shows an example where $p=0$, i.e., there are no equations $c_j^Tx=d_j$.

If $p\geq1$ then the equations $c_j^T=d_j$ $\>(1\leq j\leq p)$ define an affine subspace $V$ of ${\mathbb R}^n$, in general of dimension $n-p$. For the given problem only the points $x\in V$ are interesting. It would be possible to choose new coordinates $y_k$ in such a way that $V={\mathbb R}^{n-p}$. The inequalities $a_j^Tx\leq b_j$ $\>(1\leq j\leq m)$ would then be transcribed into inequalities in terms of the $y_k$, and we are in the situation of Figure 2.11.